# fread() does not write to string properly

Tags: c, file, fread

I am trying to use `fread()` to write the contents of a file into a char array, but it does not seem to work. Here is the part of the program where I am implementing it in. I have included a lot of trace statements to check whether each step gives the correct output. All of them seem to be perfect. The `fileSize` comes out correctly. The size of `sendFileBuf` also comes out correctly. 
When it enters the `while` loop, the `printf` statement there is executed only twice, even though the `fileSize` value is around 62000. And when I print `sendFileBuf`, it comes out with weird characters like `ÿØÿá`. I have tried it with a couple of files and there is always some error. Please help me out!

```
void sendFile(fileNode fileToSend, int sockFd)
{
    int fileSize;

    fileSize = atoi(fileToSend.fileSize);
    printf("file size after conversion to int: %d\n", fileSize);

    //Sending file size
    if(send(sockFd, fileToSend.fileSize, sizeof(fileToSend.fileSize), 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Sending file size");
        close(sockFd);
        exit(1);
    }

    //Send actual file
    FILE *newFp;
    char path[50];
    strcpy(path, "SharedFiles/");
    strcat(path, fileToSend.fileName);

    if((newFp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Write file to buffer and send
    char sendFileBuf[fileSize];
    memset(&sendFileBuf, 0, sizeof(sendFileBuf));
    printf("Size of sendfilebuf: %ld", sizeof(sendFileBuf));

    fread(&sendFileBuf, 1, fileSize, newFp);

    printf("sending file buffer %s\n", sendFileBuf);
    if(send(sockFd, sendFileBuf, sizeof(sendFileBuf), 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Sending file");
        fclose(newFp);
        close(sockFd);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `fread`. It might be failing.

Comment: If `fileToSend.fileSize` is a pointer, it would be invalid to use `sizeof(fileToSend.fileSize)` in the call to `send`; you'd want to use `strlen` instead. (If it's an array, then it's okay.)

Comment: @icktoofay - Thanks for that tip. I realized that `fread` is being executed twice. The first time it returns a value that is equal to the size of the file and the second time it returns 0. I guess that's why it is messing up the `sendFileBuf`.

Comment: @icktoofay - that part works fine. I am not using a pointer. But thanks for the heads-up on using `strlen` in case it was a pointer. Did not know that.

Comment: 'If it's an array, then it's okay' -- no, it's 1 too many.

Comment: @Bararuloke what "results" did not change? You can no longer be corrupting your send buffer by the broken while loop that no longer exists. The memset() is worthless since everything in the stack buffer (why not a heap buffer?) is overwritten with file data from the fread() (that is still not checked for success). We have no idea what is in your file (head fileName and show the output in your question). If it is asci text, you're not allocating a buffer sized for the added nullchar you must append. If it isn't and you're expecting printf will hex-conv for you. it won't.

Answer (score 2):

The while loop containing the `fread` call might not be doing what you want.  If fails to read everything in a single call, then the second call is going to read the data into the beginning of the buffer (and overwrite what was written in the first iteration).

For example, suppose the buffer is 10 bytes and the data you are reading is:

```
1234567890abcde
```

The first loop will read the first 10 characters (`1234567890`).  The second iteration will read `abcde` into the beginning of the buffer.  After that, the buffer will contain:

```
abcde67890
```

And there will not be a null terminator in the buffer then (assuming the data just read does not contain a zero in it).  So the printf would possibly include data past the end of the buffer.

Comment: I get your point, but how would you fix it?

Comment: @Mark Wilkins - But I have taken care of that issue by declaring `sendFileBuf` with the same size as the size of the file. So `fread` should get it done in one go. And I feel it does, since the return value of it is equal to the size of the file.

Comment: @Bararuloke then why the loop? Just to compute a file size? A simple seek+tell+seek will give you that, no loop required. since you already have the size anyway (and we're assuming that size is accurate), I'm trying to see what that loop is even buying you.

Comment: It sounded from the OP that it looped twice which would indicate that problem exists. Even so it could end up with no null terminator and mess up the next printf

Comment: @WhozCraig - Ya, i have realized that the loop is not required. I have removed it in my code. Will edit it here also. I have the same problem though.

Comment: @Bararuloke It may not have been the real issue. Is it *possible* that the file size reported by your fileNode structure is *not* accurate? That would explain the loop hitting twice (if fileNode.fileSize is undersized, for example). Just for sanity, do a fseek+ftell+fseek to get the *real* file size right before you buffer it up and sending it.

Comment: @WhozCraig - sorry for the late reply. Yes, the file size reported by the fileNode structure is accurate. To double check it, i used fseek + ftell + fseek also in this program and it came out the same. The results did not change. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sendFileBuf` on an expression it decays into a pointer so you don't have to dereference it `&`. Try it this way:

```
fread(sendFileBuf, 1, fileSize, newFp);
```

Same thing with `memset()`:

```
memset(sendFileBuf, 0, sizeof(sendFileBuf));
```

Comment: It does not change anything :(

Comment: Why do you do a while for `fread` if `sendFileBuf` is the same size of the file? It would make sense that the second time it gets filled with garbage. Try calling it only once.

Comment: I did it, in the sense eliminated the `while` loop and called it just once. Did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Nobody else has asked this, so here we go: You say that the function "comes out with weird characters like `ÿØÿá`".

What makes you think those characters are weird? What kind of file is it that you are trying to read? Is it a text file? Or an MP3? Or an image file? Or something else altogether?

The contents you see on the screen may be *perfectly valid* as many files contain data that is not human-readable. You are printing out (as a string) file contents that may not be strings at all.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I understand that not all files contain human readable characters and that it is completely normal for such kind of characters to come up when you print out, say a, jpg file or a non-text file. But this is happening even for text files and I sure did not enter it in them. Also for other files, I just get a couple of characters, when their size is much bigger.